# Command to add permissions to user under ESXi 4.1 via console

Tags: ssh, vmware-esxi, user-permissions

So I don't have to give them the password for the root account, wich is shared with other services, I need to add administrator rules to another user in several (30+) ESXi 4.1.0 servers. Creating the user isn't very complicated, but giving him the permissions invlves modifying `/etc/hostd/authorization.xml`. That seems complicated using cssh.

I'm wondering if anyone known if there's a command to do that from ssh more easily ?

(I have been througha ll available commands but some have "cryptic" names...)

Comment: ESXi 4.1? Eww. You can use vSphere to grant permissions, too.

Comment: unfortunatly, those hosts aren't managed with vCenter =/

Comment: They don't have to be. You can use the actual vSphere client that you install on your workstation.

Comment: Yeah but I would like to avoid to do 30 times the same thing. I'm wired to try to automate all I have to do.

I'll probably try to paste the XML code using cssh